# SSH2 PECL / phpseclib firewall blocking getaddrinfo fail

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib, libssh2

I have a PHP based SFTP application I created and it has been working great. Now I have to put it on a server that has a firewall. I get this error:

> Message: ssh2_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

If I turn off the firewall it works fine. The firewall accepts:

- ALL outbound ports.
- All inbound 443 traffic, buts drops ALL other inbound traffic.

I read something about cURL needing port 9091 inbound open but that did not work.
I tried allowing all inbound port 22 (ssh) traffic but that did not work.
I tried allowing all inbound port 80 (http) traffic but still not working.
I tried using phpseclib instead of SSH2 PECL, but still get the same type of error.

Does anyone have any idea what inbound port has to be open?
Or have any ideas on what else might be going on?

Comment: Allow `RELATED` traffic to come in as well, otherwise, how is a DNS response ever to return to your server?

Comment: After a lot of trial and error I found that SSH2 requires ports 22, 101, and 115.

Comment: well, 22 suffices here for _outbound_, inbound = random port..., but ssh2 does not fail, the translation from a name to an IP fails before ssh even starts... Try it with an IP instead of a name & see the difference.